# AWS COPY From S3 Command Fails As A Result of Truncation - RESOLVED

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

First of all I would like to mention that I tried searching for this issue in existing SO questions but I couldn't find the scenario I came across. Hence asking a new question.

So I am trying to import data from S3 to Redshift.

The data in S3 is JSON data seperated by new line character i.e. `\n` (exported using UNLOAD command from other redshift cluster)

The copy command is -

```
copy redhist_table_name
from 's3://bucket/path/to/s3/json/file.json'
iam_role 'iam_role_info'
region 'region';
json 'auto';
```

The STL_LOAD_ERRORS shows error as - `delimiter not found` **but when I looked closely, I found that the copy command is copying only first 1024 characters from the json row which results in above error**

I looked for all the options that copy command offers to see if there's way to increase this limit but I found none.

Any ideas where is this limit coming from? Or is this not the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I expect this is not the root cause.  Stl_load_errors only stores 1024 characters in the "raw_line" column.  There very well may be a limit to how long a line can be but I know that it is much longer than 1024 characters.

Which line in the file is COPY failing on?  First or somewhere later in the file?

If a line deep in the file there may be something off about it.  UNLOAD to COPY should work correctly but I can see that there may be some corner cases (like " in string values).  If it a specific line then posting that line (sanitized if need be) would be helpful.

Comment: You are right, the truncation was caused by the character limit on the column in stl_load_errors table. This issue was basically because of extra new line characters & quotes in one of the column data. Thanks for the help!